# Seeking tool to work out overlap between two polygon layers and their statistics using QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, geoprocessing

I have two polygons in QGIS. One is a land-use map, which polygons that include different types (forest, agriculture, urban etc). I also have a vector polygon that represents a flood extent. I want to work out the amount of flooded land-use types, so that I get:

```
Forest - 5,000m2
Agriculture - 15,000m2
Urban - 10,000m2
```

(for example)

What is the correct tool to do this analysis?

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to answer your question (imho) : a good **SQL query** using QGIS DB Manager.

You choose **Database / Database Manager / Database Manager** then **Virtual Layers / Qgis Layers** and you can then try the following query *(you open the SQL window by clicking on the 'wrench' icon)* :

```
SELECT LU.type, sum(st_area(st_intersection(LU.geometry,FLO.geometry)) FROM LU, FLO
where st_intersects(LU.geometry,FLO.geometry)
GROUP BY LU.type
```

*I called **LU** the land use table and **FLO** the flood table.*

You get the cumulated areas of land types in your flooded zone. Once executed u can retrieve the result in your QGIS session :

*Check the CheckBox **"Load as new layer"**, fill in the fields expected by QGIS and then click on **"Load Now !"** - The result of your query will appear in the layer manager.*

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific on how to "...retrieve the result..."?

Comment: I edited my answer a bit.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways that this could be tackled, quite a simple way would be to use the

Vector - Geoprocessing tools - Clip

to create a new layer with just the areas of land-use that are within the flood area. Layers need to be in the same CRS.

You could then use

Vector - Geoprocessing - Dissolve

to dissolve each land-use types into single polygons and then use the Field Calculator to recalculate the area of each land-use type polygon

Use area$ in the field calculator to return an area value. You may need to divide the function by an amount to convert it into a unit that is most useful. This will depend on the CRS. For hectares for example in a metric CRS this would be $area/10000.

Comment: `$area` not `area$`